# Why does not filter Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

In HTML template I have directive `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in friendList.active | filter:searchName">
```

Also input field with `ng-model="searchName"`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchName" maxlength="10" placeholder="">
```

When I typing text blocks inside `ng-repeat` is not sorted, why?

Response `friendList.active` AJAX is:

```
{"534":{"name":"Danil","photo":"http://who.com/public/images/non_photo_user.png","id":"534","unread":null,"online":0},"541":{"name":"Aysel Bukarova","photo":"http://who.com/public/images/non_photo_doctor.png","id":"541","unread":null,"online":0}}
```

Comment: More code needed. Errors in console?

Comment: I think you missed to set the name for input, after you will set name, it should work

Comment: There are not errors. Set attribute `name="searchName"`?

Comment: Does not work too. If do {{searchName"}} is displayed.

Comment: Check this example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OsmWLnLOLMvxrmLCFVP8?p=preview

Comment: May be problem that I get on time `friendList.active` from AJAX? or wrong format response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tou need to convert the response object in the array because the filter is working with arrays. Or you can write your own filter that will work with the properties of the object. See the sample from **Rise Ledger**. Name for input field is not required.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer is solution. I have converted and all work fine

Comment: If indexes are not required (you have an 'id' in each item) then you can convert object on server side.